# missing some text when parsing article content with lxml, what is the issue?

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing, lxml, article

I am using the following code to parse an article from a french news site. When getting all the paragraphs, i keep missing some text. why is that?

Here is my code: the code with the XX is the most relevant the other parts is just me putting it in my own structure for use.

```
def getWordList(sent,wordList):
    listOfWords = list((sent).split())
    for i in listOfWords:
       i = i.replace("."," ")
       i = i.replace(","," ")
       i = i.replace('\"'," ")
       valids = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z]+", '', i)
       if(len(i) > 3 and (i.lower() not in stopWords) and i.isnumeric() != 
True and valids):
           wordList[valids] = {}
           wordList[valids]["definition"] = ""
           wordList[valids]["status"] = ""
def parse(link):

    page = requests.get(link)

    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    XXword = tree.xpath('//*[@class="article__content  old__article-content-single"]')
    articleContent = {}
    articleContent["words"] = {}
    articleContent["language"] = "French";
    wordList = articleContent["words"]
    contentList = []
    XXpTag = word[0].xpath('//*')
    pText = {}
    for x in range(len(pTag)):
        #print(pTag[x].get("class"))
        if(pTag[x].text != None):
            if(pTag[x].tail != None):
                print("tail")
                XXtext = pTag[x].text + pTag[x].tail
            else:
                print("no tail")
                XXtext = pTag[x].text
            XXif(pTag[x].get("class") == "article__paragraph "):
                print(pTag[x].get("class"))
                print(text)
                getWordList(text,wordList)
                pText[text] = {}
                pText[text]["status"] = ""
                pText[text]["type"] = "p"
            XXelif(pTag[x].get("class") == "article__sub-title"):
                print(pTag[x].get("class"))
                getWordList(text,wordList)
                pText[text] = {}
                pText[text]["status"] = ""
                pText[text]["type"] = "h2"
```

here is an example article link: https://www.lemonde.fr/economie/article/2019/05/23/vivendi-chercherait-a-ceder-universal-music-group-au-chinois-tencent_5466130_3234.html

I am successfully getting all the highlighted text but the rest is missing,***not the text in the middle* i am successfully avoiding that**. I just want the text in between which is not being included.
[image]

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: What do you mean by "not the text in the middle i am successfully avoiding that"? Is that the segment which begins by "Lire aussi"?

Comment: yes, i dont know if that comment was necessary, i was just tying to make sure people dont get stuck trying to get those links. I just one the text in the main paragraphs.

Comment: What is `getWordList()`?

Comment: its function that i use to get a every word in a sentence in to a list, that works fine

Comment: Even it if works fine, you need to post it, or else your code above can't be checked.

Comment: ok, i will edit and post it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the content of tags containing other tags. For example, there are `<em>` emphasized text tags in the `<p>` paragraph tags.

Use the `text_content()` method instead of `text` to get the full content of your paragraphs:

```
text = pTag[x].text_content() + pTag[x].tail
```

and

```
text = pTag[x].text_content()
```